# WPF - StackPanel Hide Content to Left

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel

I'm trying to insert an list of button in a StackPanel
But I'd like to  hide the wrap content to left instead of right, as it is currently doing

[image]

Here my is code xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
    <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
    <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
    <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
    <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
    <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
    <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
    <TextBox x:Name="EDT_NUMERO_CFOP" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxNoBorder}" Height="30"></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

I think that there's something like "hideToLeft"

Comment: Use a WrapPanel ?

Comment: but is there some property that  can  always show the last elemente ? cause I tried the WrapPanel it only created a new line

Comment: May not be what you want when there's few to show, but you could try changing the horizontal alignment to make it right aligned. Otherwise, I am going to say the answer is no to anything out of the box.

Comment: Basically you're looking for is a feature like 'freeze column' as seen on spreadsheet/grids ? I think you should edit your question to explain what you're really looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the **StackPanel** inside **ScrollViewer** with **FlowDirection property  = RightToLeft**

```
   <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,6,6.5" >
        <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
        <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
        <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
        <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
        <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
        <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
        <Button Width="50">1.5678</Button>
        <TextBox x:Name="EDT_NUMERO_CFOP" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxNoBorder}"  Height="30"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image: flow from right to left]

Comment: Thank you  it was exactly  what I was looking for